# How to pass id from one store to be used in another in Sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 stores, one for events and one for data captured for that event. I am trying to get the id from the events store and use it in the data store. I have the following field in my data model:

> { name: 'eventId', type: 'int' },

My controller fetches the form data, validates it and after this, my code fails. I am trying the following to get the id from the first store and then set it in the second store

```
var idStore = Ext.getStore('Details');
var id = idStore.findRecord('id');

currentData.set('eventId', newValues.id);
```

My console returns `null` for `var id`, which leads me to believe that my code is wrong, can someone help explain to me how I fetch the id and use it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the docs [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findRecord) say to specify the value after the field. All I had to do was to add '1' after the 'id' field.

This does raise some questions though, I have to ensure that my id's always start with '1', does anyone know of a better way?